# Compactness of a set in order topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider a partial order in $R^2$ given by the relation $(x_1,y_1)<(x_2,y_2)$ EITHER if $x_1<x_2$ OR if $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1<y_2$.

Then in the order topology on $R^2$ defined by the above order, how can I conclude that $[0,1]$×$[0,1]$ is not compact?

**My thought**:I have two doubts.

- I am not getting how the given relation < is a partial ordering on $R^2$ when it doesn't seem to be reflexive to me. However, it is antisymmetric and transitive.
- If I agree that the relation < is a partial ordering then am I right to say that all the points of unit square [0,1]×[0,1] belong to the order topology of $R^2$? Then how it is not compact?
  Please tell me at what point I am wrong and help me to reach the result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First bullet point: consider $(x_1,y_1) \leqslant (x_2,y_2)$ if either $(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)$ or $(x_1,y_1) < (x_2,y_2)$. That's the associated weak partial (total, actually) order, which is reflexive. The original "$<$" is a strict partial order, and such beasts are by definition irreflexive.

Comment: ok..thanks for ur comment. But the second bullet is still a problem to me.

Comment: Will it be sufficient to prove that the interval [0,1] is not compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $[0,1]^2$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, so it is given a subspace topology (coming from the order topology of $\mathbb R^2$). Note that in this topology, $\{x\} \times [0,1]$ is open as 
$$\{x\} \times [0,1] = [0,1]^2 \cap\big( \{x\} \times (-0.1,1.1)\big)$$
and $\{x\} \times (-0.1,1.1)$ is open in the order topology. Then the subset of open sets

$$\{ \{x\}\times [0,1]| x\in [0,1]\}$$
is an open cover of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. But this open cover has no finite subcover.

Comment: John Ma..Thanks. I understand the geometriCal meaning of ur answer completely but how does it prove that [0,1]×[0,1] is not compact?What are the limit points which do not belong to given set w.r.t. order topology? kindly elaborate.

Comment: Do you know that a set is compact if every open cover has a finite subcover? @mathlover

Comment: yes..kindly explain it with reference to the example u have given..I

Comment: Hint 2: So to show that it is noncompact, it suffices to find an open cover which has no finite subcover. Try to use that $\{x\} \times [0,1]$ to construct such an open cover.  @mathlover

Comment: John Ma..what I understand is that ur open cover ${x}$×$(-0.1,1.1)$ contains infinite open subcovers of ${x}×[0,1]$ hence it is non compact. Will the answer be same in usual topology of $R^2$?

Comment: Please see the edit. Note that $[0,1]^2$ is compact in the usual topology. Those $\{x\}\times [0,1]$ are not open in the usual topology. @mathlover

Comment: The order on $R^2$ is called the Lexicographic Order. It is a linear order. That is,it is irreflexive,transitive,and satisfies Trichotomy.

Comment: @JohnMa I can't understand why did you introduce open cover in subspace topology,I believe that open covers has member from order topology.

Comment: @SubhajitSaha right!